# Can't pass selected value DropDownListFor to javascript function

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

My simpel test Model:

```
public class MovieModel {

    public string SelectedCategorieID { get; set; }

    public List<CategorieModel> Categories { get; set; }

    public MovieModel() {
        this.SelectedCategorieID = "0";
        this.Categories = new List<CategorieModel>() {new CategorieModel {ID = 1,
            Name = "Drama"},
        new CategorieModel {ID = 2,
            Name = "Scifi"}};
    }
}

public class CategorieModel {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My Home controller action Index:

```
    public ActionResult Index() {

        Models.MovieModel mm = new Models.MovieModel();

        return View(mm);
    }
```

My strongly typed View:

```
@model MvcDropDownList.Models.MovieModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<script type="text/javascript">
    function categoryChosen(selectedCatID) {
//        debugger;
        var url = "Home/CategoryChosen?SelectedCategorieID=" + selectedCatID;
        $.post(url, function (data) {
            $("#minicart").html(data);
        });
    }
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("CategoryChosen", "Home", FormMethod.Get)) {

    <fieldset>
        Movie Type
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCategorieID, new SelectList(Model.Categories, "ID", "Name", Model.SelectedCategorieID), "---Select categorie---")
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>

}
<input type="button" value="Minicart test" onclick="categoryChosen('@Model.SelectedCategorieID');" />
<div id="minicart">
    @Html.Partial("Information")
</div>
```

Please ignore the first input, because I'm using the second input with 'Minicart test' on it (the HTML.Beginform is there to learn something else later). The mini cart stuff is from another tutorial, I apologize. Don't let it distract you please.

When the button is clicked categoryChosen jQuery is called, which calls the action:

```
    [AcceptVerbs("POST")]
    public ActionResult CategoryChosen(string SelectedCategorieID) {

        ViewBag.messageString = SelectedCategorieID;

        return PartialView("Information");

    }
```

The partial view Information looks like this:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Information";
}

<h2>Information</h2>
<h2>You selected: @ViewBag.messageString</h2>
```

My question is why is Model.SelectCategorieID zero (Model.SelectCategorieID = 0) even after I changed the value in the dropdownlist? What am I doing wrong? Thank you very much in advance for answering. If you need any information or anything in unclear, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is why is Model.SelectCategorieID zero
>   (Model.SelectCategorieID = 0) even after I changed the value in the
>   dropdownlist?

That's because you have hardcoded that value in your onclick handler:

```
onclick="categoryChosen('@Model.SelectedCategorieID');"
```

If you want to do that properly you should read the value from the dropdown list:

```
onclick="categoryChosen(this);"
```

and then modify your categoryChosen function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function categoryChosen(ddl) {
        // debugger;
        var url = 'Home/CategoryChosen';
        $.post(url, { selectedCategorieID: $(ddl).val() }, function (data) {
            $('#minicart').html(data);
        });
    }
</script>
```

Also I would recommend you using an URL helper to generate the url to invoke instead of hardcoding it in your javascript function. And last but not least, I would recommend you doing this unobtrusively, so that you could put this in a separate javascript file and stop mixing markup and script.

So here's how your code will look like after taking into consideration my remarks:

```
@model MvcDropDownList.Models.MovieModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("CategoryChosen", "Home", FormMethod.Get)) 
{
    <fieldset>
        Movie Type
        @Html.DropDownListFor(
            m => m.SelectedCategorieID, 
            new SelectList(Model.Categories, "ID", "Name"), 
            "---Select categorie---",
            new { 
                id = "categoryDdl"
                data_url = Url.Action("CategoryChoosen", "Home") 
            }
        )
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>

}

<input type="button" value="Minicart test" id="minicart-button" />

<div id="minicart">
    @Html.Partial("Information")
</div>
```

and then in your separate javascript file unobtrusively subscribe to the click handler of your button and send the AJAX request:

```
$(function() {
    $('#minicart-button').click(function() {
        // debugger;
        var $categoryDdl = $('#categoryDdl');
        var selectedCategorieID = $categoryDdl.val();
        var url = $categoryDdl.data('url');
        $.post(url, { selectedCategorieID: selectedCategorieID }, function (data) {
            $('#minicart').html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Darin, thank you very much for your extensive reply *takes a big breath*. Ok, first of all, the answer is indeed to get the value from the DropDownList itself. So what I do now in my javascript is: var selCatID = $("#Cats").val(); (and I gave the dropdown the ID Cats ofcourse). Thank you very much for this answer.

Comment: BUT your answer gave me a few more question, because I'm very new at webdeveloping. Why was the value hardcoded if I said: @Model.SelectedCategorieID? I thought the value was stored in this property after a change event? And what is unobtrusively, setting javascript in seperate file?

Comment: What is .data('url')? Is that to extract the url the drowpdownlistbox is located on? I don't understand how that will call the action "CategoryChosen"...

Comment: @DannyvanderKraan, `@Model.SelectedCategorieID` means always pass 0 to js function. `unobtrusively` means you could get value from ddl when clicking not pass it in button click event. `data('url')` means if you define variables in html helpers, then html renders data attribute. For Darins example helper render like this `data-url` , `data-id`. [jquery-data](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

Comment: Oohh right... You mean this line: Data_url = Url.Action("CategoryChoosen", "Home"). Missed that the 1st time. Lot of information to process. Ok, thank you very much.

Comment: I've put the javscript in a seperate file and now it's not working anymore. It never calls the script as though it can't find it...

Comment: Important to note! 1) The seperate .js file needs to be loaded in _Layout.cshtml. 2) Above code from Darin is missing a comma. 3) Above code from Darin misspelled the action name (it's not CategoryChoosen but CategoryChosen). It's working now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Provide an id for your dropdownlist:**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCategorieID, new SelectList(Model.Categories, "ID",
  "Name", Model.SelectedCategorieID), new {id = "myDropDownList"})
```

**And your javascript function as follows:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function categoryChosen() {
    var cat = $("#myDropDownList").val();

    var url = "Home/CategoryChosen?SelectedCategorieID=" + cat;
    $.post(url, function (data) {
        $("#minicart").html(data);
    });
  }
</script>
```

**Why your code did not work?**

```
onclick="categoryChosen('@Model.SelectedCategorieID')
```

is generated as

```
onclick="categoryChosen('0')
```

because the value of `SelectedCategorieID` is 0 when it is generated.

Comment: Thank you. I'm doing now exactly as you answered indeed. Still don't understand why 0 is generated even after a selected index change on the dropdown. Guess it's because I'm too much of a desktop developer. ;)

Comment: @DannyvanderKraan Correct guess. When your page goes from server to client, it goes with the value 0 and it will remain the same until it returns to the server and server sends the page back with a different value, e.g. 1.