# Getting selected Enum Value from a combo box in Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, html, razor

I've loaded a combo box by this code.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.OEValue, new
SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(ICS.Base.Client.Utility.EnumOperationFunctionality))),
new { id = "cboOEValue", style = "width: 225px;" })
```

Now I want the selected value of `cboOEValue` by `EnumOperationFunctionality`.

Answer (score 0):

may [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15224920/cant-pass-selected-value-dropdownlistfor-to-javascript-function) help you

and getting value from combo box in javascript

```
var e = document.getElementById("cboOEValue ");
```

Comment: thanks but this document.getElementById("cboOEValue ") can give you the whole list but i need the selected value not list or Inner Html....

Comment: you can extract value by using e.selectedIndex

Answer (score 0):

All items inside a combo box shared a same “name” attribute.
If you're using jquery, very simple by using below to get seleted items.

```
$('input[name=OEValue]:checked')
```

Or you can use basic javascript

```
var all = document.getElementsByName('OEValue');
var selected = [];
for(var i = 0; i < all.length; i++){ 
    if(all[i].checked) 
        selected.push(all[i].value);
}
```